# Regex to exclude certain errors from a log

Tags: regex, error-logging

I am new to this so would appreciate your help on writing a regex for this.

I have a log of errors that are fine however I would like to exclude certain error types from being reported as they are known errors:

Here is an example of a good log error

```
12/09/2012 11:30:01 AM : [ERROR] : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'sys_utc_updated'.
```

In the same log file, I would like to exclude line of errors that have this type:

```
12/09/2012 12:12:01 [0] 30-Error: Invalid index command: "/search.asp".
```

and exclude lines of errors with this type:

```
12/09/2012 04:12:06 [2] 30-Error: Action failed - unencrypted communication is not allowed : "ACTION=GETSTATUS".
```

I tried writing this regex but I don't think I got it correct:

```
/(?:(?:Error)(?:ERROR)(?:[^Invalid\ index\ command]*))|(?:(?:Action\ failed\ \-\ unencrypted\ communication\ is\ not\ allowed))/im
```

Comment: Why not load the log file into something like Excel and do the filtering in that?

Answer (score 0):

From your example, a simple `/30-Error/` would be sufficient. Or even `/Error/` if you're matching case-sensitive.

Comment: thanks for your input, its a little more tricky than first thought as the value 30 changes and the error variable have a pattern that need an exclusion on. I am nearly there with my regex complete, just putting it through the testing phases and tweaking it as i go along